# How to modify mapnik's buffer-size by kosmtik's localconfig.json/.js?

Tags: mapnik, cartocss

I want to override [mapnik's buffer-size](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/XMLConfigReference) in [kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik). How to override it in localconfig.json/.js?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: for exporting mapnik's xml (it's hacky)

```
exports.LocalConfig = function (localizer, project) {
    var s = project.mml.Stylesheet[0];
    s.data = s.data.replace("Map {", "Map { buffer-size: 512;\n");
};
```

**Soluton2**: for rendering tiles:

```
exports.LocalConfig = function (localizer, project) {
    project.mml.bufferSize = 2560;
};
```